# How to select one row if two have the same ID and data except one column

Tags: mysql, duplicates

My problem seemed pretty complex to me and I almost solved it. To keep it simple, I have a set of rows coming from recursive SELECTs which I will explain after the main goal in case someone has a simple solution.

First, here are my (simplified) data:

| id | account_managers | lead_am_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2, 141 | 2 |
| 1 | 2, 141 | NULL |
| 2 | 16 | NULL |
| 3 | 6, 12 | NULL |
| 4 | 6, 11 | NULL |

I don't want the 2nd row. I only want to keep one row by 'id', if there is duplicate keep the row which have a 'lead_am_id' value. So my attempt was (simplified query):

```sql
SELECT contract_with_lead_am.*, MAX(contract_with_lead_am.lead_am) AS lead_am_id
FROM contract_with_lead_am
GROUP BY contract_with_lead_am.id;
```

This worked in my development environment, but failed in production with the following error:

> Error: ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP: Expression #17 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'contract_with_lead_am.lead_am' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by">

If anyone knows how to fix this, I would be grateful.

Now for the detailed problem, here is the full query:

```sql
SELECT contract_with_lead_am.*, MAX(contract_with_lead_am.lead_am) AS lead_am_id
FROM (SELECT distinct contracts_with_am.*, IF(contracts_users.is_lead=1, contracts_users.users_id, NULL) AS lead_am
        FROM (SELECT contracts.*, group_concat(contracts_users.users_id SEPARATOR ", ") AS account_managers
                FROM contracts LEFT JOIN contracts_users ON contracts.id = contracts_users.contracts_id 
                WHERE contracts_users.type = 1
                GROUP BY contracts.id
                ORDER BY contracts.id DESC) contracts_with_am 
LEFT JOIN contracts_users ON contracts_with_am.id = contracts_users.contracts_id) contract_with_lead_am
GROUP BY contract_with_lead_am.id;
```

This requires a bit of explanation. I have a 'contracts' table which contains all of my contracts with an 'id' PK and a 'contracts_users' table which make relations between 'users' and 'contracts' defining who is commercial (contracts_users.type=0) and who is account manager (contracts_users.type=1).

For some server reasons, I need to get all my account managers' id on the same row. So I use the group_concat() function with a ', ' separator to be usable on my server. There is also a Lead Account_manager which is found in the 'contracts_users' table. My thought was to test from my rows IF() my account manager is the Lead (contracts_users.is_lead=1), I put the contracts_users.users_id (account manager ID) in the column 'lead_am'. After this, I still have the duplicate problem I explained above so I thought of using GROUP BY again with MAX(). It worked in development but failed in production.

Here are (simplified again) tables I used:

#### contracts

| field name | type |
| --- | --- |
| id | INT (PK) |
| some_data | VARCHAR |

#### users

| field name | type |
| --- | --- |
| id | INT (PK) |
| some_data | VARCHAR |

#### contracts_users

| field name | type |
| --- | --- |
| users_id | INT (PK, FK) |
| contracts_id | INT (PK, FK) |
| type | INT |
| is_lead | INT |

Answer (score 0):

Just to let everyone know, I found a way with the query below:

```
SELECT contract_with_lead_am.*
FROM (SELECT distinct contracts_with_am.*, ANY_VALUE(IF(contracts_users.is_lead=1, contracts_users.users_id, NULL)) AS lead_am
    FROM (SELECT contracts.*, ANY_VALUE(group_concat(contracts_users.users_id SEPARATOR ", ")) AS account_managers
        FROM contracts LEFT JOIN contracts_users ON contracts.id = contracts_users.contracts_id 
        WHERE contracts_users.type = 1
        GROUP BY contracts.id) contracts_with_am 
LEFT JOIN contracts_users ON contracts_with_am.id = contracts_users.contracts_id) contract_with_lead_am
GROUP BY contract_with_lead_am.id
UNION
SELECT contracts.*, ANY_VALUE(NULL) AS account_managers, ANY_VALUE(NULL) AS lead_am
FROM contracts RIGHT JOIN contracts_users ON contracts.id = contracts_users.contracts_id
GROUP BY contracts.id
HAVING COUNT(*) < 2
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

I made two query with the data I needed and used UNION. I also added ANY_VALUE() to bypass the error "ER_WRONG_FIELD_WITH_GROUP".